# What is Active Record - design pattern or module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Basically what's the difference between design pattern, module and some other terms we use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite a difficult question to answer.

It depends, basically.

Active Record is both, it's a design pattern in the traditional sense, [described](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) by [Martin Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler) in [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html). But, ActiveRecord (note no space) could be classed as a module, since it's an implementation of the Active Record design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different perspective, ActiveRecord:Ruby - Hibernate:Java. Both are ORM Frameworks and solve the recurring problem of persisting to database and converting data from RDBMS to OO Models. So, you can call it both a Design Pattern & Module or more specifically ORM.